# Getting raw data using DcRaw

Tags: image-processing, import, image

I'm using dcraw program to import raw image data to *Mathematica*. When I use `Run["dcraw -4 -D -T  "image.nef"]` (which converts it to an unprocessed linear TIFF file) and then `Import["image.tiff","Data"]`, I basically import the raw data to *Mathematica*.

Afterwards I use `Image[Import["image.tiff","Data"]]` command to see the image using the extracted data, but it is DIFFERENT than the `Import["image.tiff"]` image, WHY?

Comment: You should probably not use `Image[Import[...]]`; Import already returns an `Image` object. Instead you should save the image returned by `Import` into a variable, e.g. `img = Import["path/to/yourimage"]`. Evaluating `img` will already show that image. I suppose that the difference you see may come from the fact that running `Image` on an object that is already a bitmap image might cause it to be rasterized a second time, leading to loss of quality, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It would have been best if you post the TIFF file (upload it somewhere).  Without it, my best guess is this:

`data = Import["file.tiff", "Data"]` will import the integers stored in the TIFF.  These may have various ranges depending of the type of TIFF file.  For an 8-bit one, you'll get values between 0..255, for a 16-bit one between 0..65535, etc.

`data` only has the raw data from the image file without any meta information such as what range of values should be assumed.  `Image[data]` thus assumed a default range of 0..1 and creates a `Real` type image ([`ImageType`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageType.html)).  Thus in your case you should manually specify the type of image you want to create, e.g. `Image[data, "Bit16"]` as `dcraw` outputs 16-bit files with the `-4` option.

---

If you want to import the data as an image, just use `Import["file.tiff"]`. Also note that since version 10.1 Mathematica can import NEF files directly, without any help from `dcraw`.